# Can I force draw after setContentView call?

Tags: android

in my activity I run code that takes a while to execute, but does not change the UI.
It seems that Android waits for all the code in onCreate to be executed to draw the UI.

Is there any way to force the drawing before executing the long code or I must execute my long lasting code in a thread?

Thanks

Comment: you must execute the code in a thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always create `Thread` for time taking process. Also in some of your scenarios i.e. on low-end device you will face infamous `ANR` dialog

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned that your UI is drawn delayed because of the long runing code you could try this:

```
runOnUIThread(new Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // do setup here
    }
}
```

But if your code is performing for a long time you should accept [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581841/can-i-force-draw-after-setcontentview-call/7581898#7581898).